# Создание сгруппированных вложенных списков

Tags: python, list

Есть следующий список со списками:

```
list1 = [['Клиент 1', 'Товар 1', 100, 200], ['Клиент 2', 'Товар 2', 50, 100], ['Клиент 3', 'Товар 3', 200, 300], ['Клиент 1', 'Товар 1', 20, 50], ['Клиент 2', 'Товар 2', 60, 60]]
```

Хочу получить сгруппированный список по первому (Клиент) и второму (Товар) элементу во вложенном списке в виде ниже. 3 и 4 элементы вложенного списка должны быть просуммированы.

```
result = [['Клиент 1', 'Товар 1', 120, 250], ['Клиент 2', 'Товар 2', 110, 160], ['Клиент 3', 'Товар 3', 200, 300]]
```

Пробовал код ниже, выдает ошибку:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
list1 = [['Клиент 1', 'Товар 1', 100, 200], ['Клиент 2', 'Товар 2', 50, 100], ['Клиент 3', 'Товар 3', 200, 300], ['Клиент 1', 'Товар 1', 20, 50], ['Клиент 2', 'Товар 2', 60, 60]]
result = [[cl, pr, sum(map(itemgetter(2), qty1)), sum(map(itemgetter(3), qty2))] for cl, pr, qty1, qty2 in groupby(list1, itemgetter(0))]
print(result)
```

Подскажите, как сгруппировать вложенные списки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать словарь с ключами типа `(клиент, товар)` для группировки (кортеж может быть использован в качестве ключа словаря).

```
def group(lst):
    groups = {}
    for client, product, third, fourth in lst:
        groups.setdefault((client, product), [0, 0])
        groups[(client, product)][0] += third
        groups[(client, product)][1] += fourth
    return groups

list1 = [
            ['Клиент 1', 'Товар 1', 100, 200],
            ['Клиент 2', 'Товар 2', 50, 100],
            ['Клиент 3', 'Товар 3', 200, 300],
            ['Клиент 1', 'Товар 1', 20, 50],
            ['Клиент 2', 'Товар 2', 60, 60]
        ]
# Переделываем словарь в двумерный список
result = [[*key, *value] for key, value in group(list1).items()]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Функцию `group` можно доработать для произвольного количества суммируемых полей:

```
def group(lst):
    groups = {}
    for client, product, *others in lst:
        groups.setdefault((client, product), [0] * len(others))
        for idx, val in enumerate(others):
            groups[(client, product)][idx] += val
    return groups
```

**Output**

```
[['Клиент 1', 'Товар 1', 120, 250],
 ['Клиент 2', 'Товар 2', 110, 160],
 ['Клиент 3', 'Товар 3', 200, 300]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно попробовать так, если не особо важен формат вывода

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [['Клиент 1', 'Товар 1', 100, 200],
         ['Клиент 2', 'Товар 2', 50, 100],
         ['Клиент 3', 'Товар 3', 200, 300],
         ['Клиент 1', 'Товар 1', 20, 50],
         ['Клиент 2', 'Товар 2', 60, 60]]

df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
result = df.groupby([0, 1]).sum().reset_index()

print(result)
```

вывод:

```
          0        1    2    3
0  Клиент 1  Товар 1  120  250
1  Клиент 2  Товар 2  110  160
2  Клиент 3  Товар 3  200  300
```